# SSL Connection Error on Wamp

Tags: ssl

I have already buy a SSL Cretified SSL from Namecheap. Now i have it on https://www.djdanni.com and on 2 othere Website but i am always getting **SSL Connection Error** on all 3. Wuy is that? I am using Wamp Server with OpenSSL on Windows 7 Ultimate. How can i fix it?

Here is from my http-vhost.conf

    `NameVirtualHost *:443`

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.djdanni.com
    ServerAlias www.djdanni.com
    DocumentRoot L:/wamp/www
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/15929333repl_1.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/www.djdanni.com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/Bundle.crt"
    ErrorLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/1/error_log.log
    TransferLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/1/access_log.log
    LogFormat combined
    <Directory "L:/wamp/www/">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>  

    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.minirvinir.com
    ServerAlias www.minirvinir.com
    DocumentRoot L:/wamp/www/websocial
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/15929333repl_1.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/www.djdanni.com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/Bundle.crt"
    ErrorLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/2/error_log.log
    TransferLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/2/access_log.log
    LogFormat combined
    <Directory "L:/wamp/www/websocial">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>  

    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.kruttin.com
    ServerAlias www.kruttin.com
    DocumentRoot L:/wamp/www/voffapeysur.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/15929333repl_1.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/www.djdanni.com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "L:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/Bundle.crt"
    ErrorLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/3/error_log.log
    TransferLog L:/wamp/Weblog/minirvinir.com/ssl/3/access_log.log
    LogFormat combined
    <Directory "L:/wamp/www/voffapeysur.com">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to access this site using Chrome 40 and IE11. What browser are you using when you see the SSL Connection error?

> https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=djdanni.com

```
www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=minirvinir.com
www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kruttin.com
```

indicate successful handshakes for most browsers, although your choice of cipher suites could use some thought.

These settings from https://cipherli.st/ seem to be much better:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCompression off
```

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.35 beta-m (64-bit)
But i know that othere of my friends are getting the SSL Connection Error 2.
Now i have it in the httpd-vhost.conf.
But if i add this
<code>SSLCompression off</code>
the Server will not start.
But i am still getting SSL Connection Error. I know som of my friends have bin getting it 2.
Here is my httpd-ssl.conf on this link http://pastebin.com/a0TAf3Yq

Comment: ok i think it is Fixed. Thanks to Daniel S at SSL Department at NameCheap :)